# Como alterar o Private DNS na AWS

Tags: amazon-aws

Estou subindo umas maquinas na AWS e estou precisando alterar o Private DNS das maquinas, inicialmente eu estou tentando alterar em uma linux, não sei se essa alteração é interna na maquina ou no ADM da AWS... eu alterei no host e esta com o nome que eu quero, mas quando eu tento pingar não esta resolvendo... Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pretendes aceder aos teus seus servidores por `example.com` ao invés do nome que eles geram, vais ter que configurar o teu próprio servidor de DNS.

Por defeito, AWS VPC gere o DHCP por ti e vem com o DNS Server da Amazon.

Podes ler na documentação as opções ao teu dispor para resolveres a questão:

## [DHCP Options Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html)

> ### domain-name-servers
>
> The IP addresses of up to four domain name servers, or AmazonProvidedDNS. The default DHCP option set specifies AmazonProvidedDNS. If specifying more than one domain name server, separate them with commas.
>
> ### domain-name
>
> If you're using AmazonProvidedDNS in us-east-1, specify ec2.internal. If you're using AmazonProvidedDNS in another region, specify region.compute.internal (for example, ap-northeast-1.compute.internal). Otherwise, specify a domain name (for example, MyCompany.com).
>
> **Important**
>
> Some Linux operating systems accept multiple domain names separated by spaces. However, other Linux operating systems and Windows treat the value as a single domain, which results in unexpected behavior. If your DHCP options set is associated with a VPC that has instances with multiple operating systems, specify only one domain name.

Tradução livre:

> ### domain-name-servers
>
> Os endereços IP de até quatro servidores de nome de domínio, ou AmazonProvidedDNS. O conjunto de opções DHCP padrão especifica AmazonProvidedDNS. Se especificar servidor mais de um nome de domínio, separe-os com vírgulas.
>
> ### domain-name
>
> Se você estiver usando AmazonProvidedDNS em us-east-1, especifique ec2.internal. Se você estiver usando AmazonProvidedDNS em outra região, especificar region.compute.internal (por exemplo, ap-nordeste-1.compute.internal). Caso contrário, especifique um nome de domínio (por exemplo, MyCompany.com).
>
> **Importante**
>
> Alguns sistemas operacionais Linux aceitar vários nomes de domínio separados por espaços. No entanto, outros sistemas operacionais Linux e Windows tratar o valor como um único domínio, o que resulta em um comportamento inesperado. Se as suas opções de DHCP definidos está associada a uma VPC que tem casos com vários sistemas operacionais, especificar apenas um nome de domínio.

---

## Alternativa

Dado não dar para alterar sem implementação de servidores de DNS próprios, podes facilmente referenciá-lo com outro nome, com a criação de um registro `CNAME`, que terá o efeito desejado.

Para o efeito, nas zonas de DNS do local ontem tens o teu `example.com`, adicionas um registo `CNAME` tipo:

```
meuNovoNovo IN CNAME meuNomeAntigo.
```

Desta forma, quando se acede a `meuNovoNovo`, o servidor onde ele está registado vai indicar que deverão procurar a informação em `meuNomeAntigo`.